# How to store each months data in django model

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I am creating an app where people can log in and create a committee and invite another users to join their committee and then whoever joined it will pay the committee each month till the end date. and one of the users will get the committee at the end of each month, I am having an issue I dont know how to store data of users who are paying month by month. I have created all these django models. but now the missing part is the storing of each months data, so that I can show the status as pending or completed.

```
class Committee(models.Model):
    committee_creator = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    committee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    committee_members_limit = models.IntegerField()
    committee_amount_per_month = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    committee_month_period = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    committee_amount_limit = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    committee_starting_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    committee_ending_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
class Participants(models.Model):
    participants_name = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants_committee_name = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants_paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    participants_amount_paid = models.IntegerField()
    participants_payment_slip = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have one more table called PaymentDetails with payment date details as below

```
class Participants(models.Model):
    participants_name = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants_committee_name = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PaymentDetails (models.Model):
    participants_name = models.ForeignKey(Participants, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participants_paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    participants_amount_paid = models.IntegerField()
    participants_payment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    participants_payment_slip = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Now, you can have each month payment details for participants.

Comment: thanks alot, I am going to implament it